# cannot retrieve all rows from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

When am trying to retrieve all rows from database using java code am getting wrong output ie if table has 5 rows means the last row only displayed 5 times...

```
while(result.next()) {
            user = new User();  
            user.setId(result.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(result.getString("name"));
            user.setPassword(result.getString("password"));

            list.add(user);
            result = result.next();
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Resultset` logic is not correct, `Resultset.next()` works as cursor which move forward until to finish. Try

```
 while(result.next()) {
        user = new User();  
        user.setId(result.getInt("id"));
        user.setName(result.getString("name"));
        user.setPassword(result.getString("password"));

        list.add(user);

    }
```

Comment: This is the way to retrieve data. Would you please debug, and see how data has been populated to list.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this code,

```
if(result != null) {
  while(result.next()){ 
        user = new User();  
        user.setId(result.getInt("id"));
        user.setName(result.getString("name"));
        user.setPassword(result.getString("password"));

        list.add(user);

      }
    }
```